# Bug that prevents document from updating after inserting OpenXML using JS api in Office Online

Tags: office-js, ms-wopi

In November 2017, Tom Jebo gave an answer as to why when using the Office JS api to insert OpenXML into a document in Office Online, nothing appears until the page is reloaded:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/671a4649-8566-4413-8eb9-dcd016635583/document-not-visually-updating-when-inserting-openxml-into-office-online-word-document?forum=os_office

Here is a portion of the answer:

> The current design of InsertOoxml() in Officejs is that it only detects changes in hosts that support Cobalt. This is why the rendering does not change immediately when after the call to this API. After the auto-save functionality (subsequent Putfile) engages the wopi host, the new data will be rendered but if another edit from the UI occurs, this will preempt the InsertOoxml() edit which will be lost. The Officejs team has logged this as a bug and will consider whether to include this as a design change in a future update.

Can someone from the OfficeJS team provide a work around in the mean time, or a status update of when/if this bug will be fixed?

There are no PutFile Wopi requests made until after the user reloads the browser, so the autosave functionality doesn't show the updated document at any point until the user reloads the page.

Comment: Any update on this?